# Prevent Inserting an id based on date range ORACLE SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm looking to have a table with specific IDs:

```
CREATE TABLE ID (
    IDRef NUMBER (5, 0) NOT NULL
CONSTRAINT ID_PK PRIMARY KEY (IDRef));
```

And another table with date ranges (and other values)

```
CREATE TABLE CALENDAR (
    DateStart DATE NOT NULL,
    DateEnd DATE NOT NULL,
    IDRef NUMBER (5, 0) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT ID_PK FOREIGN KEY (IDRef) REFERENCES ID(IDRef));
```

I want to set it up so that a specific ID can only be entered if it does not overlap a date range (date start - date end).

So if ID 1 & 2 is inserted as such, I'd expect the below:

```
INSERT INTO CALENDAR VALUES (10-Jan-21, 14-Jan-21, 1); --> **SUCCESS**
INSERT INTO CALENDAR VALUES (10-Jan-21, 14-Jan-21, 2); --> **SUCCESS**
INSERT INTO CALENDAR VALUES (12-Jan-21, 13-Jan-21, 1); --> **FAIL**
INSERT INTO CALENDAR VALUES (15-Jan-21, 19-Jan-21, 1); --> **SUCCESS**
INSERT INTO CALENDAR VALUES (15-Jan-21, 19-Jan-21, 2); --> **SUCCESS**
```

Is this something that's possible with SQL on Oracle?

Comment: If ID table's primary key is EmployeeID, then how come CALENDAR table's IDRef references ID.IDRef? INSERT statements suggest you're inserting values into ID, while - according to what you posted - looks like as if you actually meant to insert into CALENDAR. If not, why is e.g. the 1st insert a *success* and the 3rd *fail*? What overlaps what? Where are inserts into CALENDAR, then? From my point of view, you should edit what you wrote, remove *everything* that isn't relevant ("other fields"? Nice to know they exist, but it's useless in this context). BTW these are "columns", not "fields".

Comment: You'll need a trigger to enforce this. Either that or only allow inserts through a proc that enforces rules on the way in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You definitely need a trigger to enforce the desired rule. You may try blow trigger -

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TRIG_INSERT_CALENDAR
AFTER INSERT
ON CALENDAR
DECLARE
       NUM_FLAG NUMBER := 0;
       INVALID_ROW EXCEPTION;
       PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT(INVALID_ROW, -20999);
BEGIN
     
     SELECT COUNT(*)
       INTO NUM_FLAG
       FROM CALENDAR C1
      WHERE EXISTS (SELECT NULL
                      FROM CALENDAR C2
                     WHERE C1.IDRef = C2.IDRef
                       AND ((C2.DateStart > C1.DateStart AND
                            C2.DateStart < C1.DateEnd) OR 
                            (C2.DateEnd > C1.DateStart AND
                            C2.DateEnd < C1.DateEnd)));
        
     IF NUM_FLAG > 0 THEN
        RAISE INVALID_ROW;
     END IF;
END;
/
```

[Demo.](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=6adb95e8295485c99548d48f26d04e56)

Comment: Thanks, this worked. While working further on a solution, I encountered another issue that I'm not able to solve. I've edited the question if you're able to share any ideas on how to approach.

Comment: Please post another issue with another question. Unedit all your updates from here and post a new question with your new problem.

Comment: I have posted a new issue. thanks for your help with this one!